# error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: git, git-push

Вот такое сообщение появляется при попытке использовать `push`. Здесь все:

```
$ git clone https://romanov_yu@bitbucket.org/romanov_yu/user.git
Cloning into 'user'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://romanov_yu@bitbucket.org/romanov_yu/user.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

Comment: Скажите, вы воспользовались инструкцией? Какие результаты получили?

Comment: Сейчас попробую, вариант новый, надеюсь, все получится. Через 5 минут отпишусь

Comment: Все работает, правда не так как вы советовали) Мне понадобилось просто СНЕСТИ все файлы и конфиги связвнные с git переустановить его - и, вуаля!, все работает! Но все равно спасибо за отклик!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, все решилось еще проще!

Необходимо было деинсталлировать программу iObit Uninstaller-ом + уничтожить файлы с кричащими о связи с git названиями в главной папке (/с/users/"user name"/*) и переустановить git (не забыв при этом ЗАНОВО задать свой user.name & user.email) а дальше, как обычно!

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, у вас не настроен ssh-сертификат для доступа к вашему аккаунту Bitbucket.

Воспользуйтесь специальной инструкцией по созданию и настройке ключа для Bitbucket: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

---

Для будущих читателей:

Если ссылка сломается, идите следующим путём: Логин на Bitbucket — клик по портрету в верхнем правом углу — Settings — слева SSH keys — в центре Learn how to generate a SSH key.

Копировать сюда текст инструкции считаю неуместным. Документ обновляется сотрудниками Atlassian вместе с изменением самого сервиса и будет существовать всегда, пока существует Bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема после переустановки win 10, просто поставил portable x64 версию git и все заработало.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/226627)

Comment: _"поставил portable x64 версию"_ - обычно portable-версии не ставятся.

Comment: @Viktorov, вроде содержится?

Comment: @Qwertiy для меня этот ответ выглядит как " А вот у меня с портативной версией такой проблемы не возникло". Не понимаю, где тут решение проблемы. На мой взгляд ответ тянет на комментарий вида "Попробуйте установить portable версию"

Comment: @Viktorov, если установленная версия как-то повреждена, то портативная поможет, поскольку использует независимые настройки. Судя по ответу автора вопроса (полное удаление установленной версии с использованием спец-утилит), вариант с портативной версией тоже является решением.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен, с вашими объяснениями это может быть ответом. Но в текущей редакции ответ тянет только на комментарий.

Comment: @Qwertiy по-моему это вопрос семантики, для меня portable версии можно и "поставить", только это делается проще, если вы об этом.